# Dragon Warrior 2: Unable to get the water flying cloth

Tags: dragon-quest-series

I'm playing Dragon Warrior 2.  I've given the magic loom and the yarn to don mahone, but he always says he's not done.  I've saved my deeds on the imperial scrolls, exited the game, and re-loaded my save but it always says he's not done.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, it's usually polite to give a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bah.  Inventory was full, so his response was the oh-so-informative "Be patient, I'm not done yet".